# How to get the value of the text box from a HTML Coded String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a string like

```
var str='<input type="text" name="se_tbox" value="Beauty is Fake" />';
```

I want to get only the value of that input box which is stored in str as `Beauty is Fake`

is there anyway to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(str).val(); // this would do it...
```

[have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/xyRc8/)

Answer (score 5):

```
var str='<input type="text" name="se_tbox" value="Beauty is Fake" />';
alert($(str).attr('value'));
// or
alert($(str).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery

```
$('<input type="text" name="se_tbox" value="Beauty is Fake" />').val()
```

or regular expression

```
'<input type="text" name="se_tbox" value="Beauty is Fake" />'.match(/value="([^"]*)"/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$(str).val();
```

Comment: why would someone downvote this? its the same as the 5 and 4 voted answers above!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't stringify your HTML to process it.
But if you have to, you can use a regexp to get the value:

```
var val = '<input value="Beauty is Fake" />'.match(/value="([^\"]+)/)[1];
```